# Prove ths sum of $\small\sqrt{x^2-2x+16}+\sqrt{y^2-14y+64}+\sqrt{x^2-16x+y^2-14y+\frac{7}{4}xy+64}\ge 11$

Tags: inequality

Let $x,y\in R$.show that
$$\color{crimson}{f(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2-2x+16}+\sqrt{y^2-14y+64} + \sqrt{x^2-16x+y^2-14y+\frac{7}{4}xy+64} \ge 11}$$

Everything I tried has failed so far.use Computer found this inequality   $\color{blue}=$ iff only if $\color{blue}{x=2,y=6}$

Here is one thing I tried, but obviously didn't work.
$$f(x,y)=\sqrt{(x-1)^2+15}+\sqrt{(y-7)^2+15}+\sqrt{(x-8)^2+(y-7)^2+\dfrac{7}{4}xy-49}$$

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Moo That is not optimal.

Comment: @Moo The OP said the inequality is "$\color{blue}=$" (i.e. an equality) iff $x=2, y=6$.  That's certainly right.

Comment: @function sug Could you please provide more context about this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For convenience, we make the translation $x=2+a$ and $y=6+b$, so that the equality case is $a=b=0$. Then the expression to bound is:
$$\sqrt{(a+1)^2+15}+\sqrt{(b-1)^2+15}+\sqrt{\frac{7}{8}(a+b)^2+\frac{1}{8}(a-6)^2+\frac{1}{8}(b+6)^2} $$
Now recall the following form of Cauchy-Schwarz for $n$ nonnegative variables $x_1, \cdots, x_n$:
$$\sqrt{n(x_1+\cdots+x_n)}=\sqrt{(1+\cdots+1)(x_1+\cdots+x_n)}\ge \sqrt{x_1}+\cdots+\sqrt{x_n}$$
with equality iff $x_1=\cdots=x_n$. We use this three times, keeping in mind the equality case $a=b=0$:
$$\sqrt{(a+1)^2+15}=\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{16((a+1)^2+15)}\ge \frac{1}{4}(|a+1|+15)$$
$$\sqrt{(b-1)^2+15}=\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{16((b-1)^2+15)}\ge \frac{1}{4}(|b-1|+15)$$
$$\sqrt{\frac{7}{8}(a+b)^2+\frac{1}{8}(a-6)^2+\frac{1}{8}(b+6)^2}\ge \frac{1}{4}\sqrt{2((a-6)^2+(b+6)^2)}\ge \frac{1}{4}(|a-6|+|b+6|)$$
Now since $|a-6|+|a+1|\ge 7$ and $|b+6|+|b-1|\ge 7$ by the triangle inequality, the expression must be at least $\frac{15}{2}+\frac{7}{2}=11$, as required.

Comment: nice approach ! Should not the 15 's be square rooted ? I hope this can be fixed.

Comment: The $15$ is being split up $15$ ways, as $1+1+\cdots+1$ (because all of the terms in the CS should be equal), so the $15$ on the right side is $15\sqrt{1}=15$ as it should be.

Comment: ah!! I see ! I was just wondering why there was 16 there also. Very nice.

Comment: Well you should be proud this was definitely one of the tougher problems, and you have an elegant solution.

Comment: Great solution! I wish I could have upvoted twice!